# What is the smallest file size Ubuntu VirtualBox image with a GUI?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, gui

I'm looking to install a few isolated applications that have a GUI onto multiple VirtualBox images. What is the smallest Ubuntu VirtualBox image file size with a GUI?

Comment: Very interesting question. Opening a Lubuntu guest in VirtualBox with installed Guest Additions, I get 320x80, not counting Status and Title Bars. Any size greater than this, you can do.

Comment: @Redbob I believe the OP is asking as in smallest image size on disk, MB/GB etc.. Can the OP confirm?

Comment: Really, @nullmeta, otherwise he would have mentioned "resolution". it depends on what OP are proposed to run, specially talking about GUI. Lubuntu and Xubuntu are recommended, as they are lightweight.

Comment: Yes I meant file size not resolution.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ What kind of GUI, the dependencies of your programs and their GUI dependencies are important... can you name your programs?

Comment: microWattOS is Ubuntu based distro with i3 as their DE. The image fit into a CD. So it is below 700MB. Their latest still based on 16.04 though. Also Bodhi Linux just released a new image based on 18.04, about the same size. They use Enlightment as their DE. Maybe you can look into them.

Comment: Do you want the smallest VDI file size (hard drive) or OVA file (exported appliance)?

Comment: There is also *CrunchEee*, specially made for really EeePC made by Asus (10 inch) and with few power/RAM, but this OS isn't in english

Comment: you can also watch at this post, more detailled : https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar/1049504#1049504

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Lubuntu 16.04 is probably best and needs 4 GB minimum

I asked a similar for the smallest footprint / fastest flavour of Ubuntu here: [Is one distribution better for Virtualbox 5.1 inside Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051964/is-one-distribution-better-for-virtualbox-5-1-inside-ubuntu-16-04) and the answer was **Lubuntu**.

I created my Lubuntu 16.04 Virtual Image at 7 GB:

[image: Lubuntu allocated.png]

With nothing of significance installed other than the base packages it's showing `3.9 GB` used and `3.5 GB` available:

[image: Lubuntu used]

So I would say the **minimum** you could get away with is **4 GB** using Lubuntu 16.04.

That said, my Ubuntu Unity 16.04.5 LTS installation with reams of applications installed and 3 kernel chains only takes up **9.8 GB**. Next time around I'll probably just go with this version and forgo the extra effort of learning new interfaces and applications such as File Manager and File Editor.

Comment: Huh?  You got all the bounty even though it was awarded by the community and though I posted first?  I thoughts it would be split evenly...

Comment: @Fabby The OP appears to have accepted the answer based on the green checkmark but I don't remember that happening. Maybe the OP manually awarded the bounty?

Comment: Makes sense: OP accepted pretty pictures, Community user awarded bounty straight after! **Congratulations! ;-)**

Answer (score 2):

The smallest official (and on-topic here) [Ubuntu flavour](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours) with a GUI is [Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) and [the minimal disk size is 3GB and the minimum memory requirements are 512MB](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu) resulting in 3.5 GB for a VM. (theoretical minimum, [anything more](https://askubuntu.com/a/1068711/344926) is better)

#### ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @dschinn1001 that's hard to have HDD/SSD that have a size under 4 GB, even the RAM have a higher size now (but old computer that have more than 20 years old can have a problem with that though)

Comment: @damadam the OP is asking about a [Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) (A computer inside a computer), so it's just a file...

Comment: @damadam - sorry, I have misread the infos after command free - also, lubuntu here on an antique laptop is only using 1 GB of 50 GB hard-disk - but would mean then, that less than 4 GB is required.

Comment: @dschinn1001 We're going by official numbers...  Yes, it can be done with less, but then the instructions become much more eleborate